# Suitable frameworks for drawing real-time graphs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meteor, maps

I have a PostgreSQL 9.5 database with GPS data [{x,y,z,t}].
I want to draw a track in real-time.

The possible frameworks options I am considering are :-
MeteorJS, AngularJS, ReactJS, KnockoutJS, NodeJS

What would be a good choice depending the complexity and their usability?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Because this isn't a specific programming question, you'll find that the helpful community here will lock this topic and also won't provide you with alternative locations to get your answer. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most popular frameworks out there for drawing graphs in HTML is **HighCharts**. You can start learning @ http://www.highcharts.com/ and the api @ http://api.highcharts.com/

The documentation is one of the best there is and the complexity is quite easy because they have a wide variation of [demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo) provided.